# Getting "java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.font" during exporting report with string like "it's&nbsp;test<"

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports

I'm working with *Jaspersoft iReport Designer 4.0.2*

Product Version: Jaspersoft iReport Designer 4.0.2
Java: 1.6.0_25; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 20.0-b11

I have a query in report which return this kind of result :

```
<div align="right"><font color="3366FF"><b><font size="3">it's&nbsp;test</font></b></font></div>
```

This is the code in *JasperReports*'s report related to the textField: `$F{TEXT}`

```xml
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="10" y="21" width="145" height="30"/>
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000066"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
        </box>
        <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
            <font fontName="Arial" size="8" pdfFontName="arial.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
            <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional" rightIndent="10" spacingAfter="1"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{TEXT}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

as you I used **markup="html"**  in order to display  the correct result in my pdf  which will be generated , in my example I should display : **it's test**

bu when I run my example I have this error :

```
sun.font.StandardTextSource@1ddfca[start:0, len:5, cstart:0, clen:5, chars:"645 631 641 642 200b", level:1, flags:9, font:java.awt.Font[family=Arial,name=Arial,style=plain,size=8], frc:java.awt.font.FontRenderContext@2496298, cm:sun.font.CoreMetrics@40ebf000]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.createCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:608)
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getCharinfo(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:492)
    at sun.font.ExtendedTextSourceLabel.getLineBreakIndex(ExtendedTextSourceLabel.java:438)
    at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.calcLineBreak(TextMeasurer.java:308)
    at java.awt.font.TextMeasurer.getLineBreakIndex(TextMeasurer.java:544)
    at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextOffset(LineBreakMeasurer.java:340)
    at java.awt.font.LineBreakMeasurer.nextLayout(LineBreakMeasurer.java:422)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderNextLine(TextMeasurer.java:649)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderParagraph(TextMeasurer.java:418)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.measure(TextMeasurer.java:362)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.chopTextElement(JRFillTextElement.java:1151)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.prepare(JRFillTextField.java:540)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:329)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:419)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:378)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2038)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:760)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:270)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:58)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:417)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:247)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:203)
```